# Command works in terminal but not as alias in profile.d

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a problem regarding an alias file in `/etc/profile.d/`. This isn't anything important. I'm just interested why it isn't working as expected.

So basically I have the file `00-alias.sh` at the path mentioned above and I wanted to make a shortcut which reads a specific line of a file. So this is my code:

```
alias lnn='sed -n "${1}p" < "${2}"'
```

With that code I should be able to perform a command like

```
$ lnn 4 test.txt
```

However, this doesn't work. I simply get the error

`-bash: : No such file or directory`

---

Now I thought, ok, maybe relative paths aren't working because the file is located at the path `/etc/profile.d/00-alias.sh`

So I went ahead and made a new alias like

```
alias pwd2='echo $(pwd)'
```

Then updated the profile.d with

`source /etc/profile.d/00-alias.sh`

And just tried `pwd2` but that echoed the path I was currently in. So in theory the file can be found with the command I wrote. I still tried to pass the file to my alias with absolute path like

```
$ lnn 4 /var/test.txt
```

Still same error as above.

---

But, if I enter the command of the alias in the terminal like

```
sed -n "4p" < test.txt
```

It works perfectly fine. No matter if I put quotes around `test.txt`

---

And here is another weird thing: If I write

```
alias lnn='sed -n "${1}p" < ${2}'
```

without the quotes around `${2}` I get the error

```
-bash: ${2}: ambiguous redirect
```

In the terminal it works just fine...

So, what am I doing wrong? Does anyone have an idea on this? I'd love to know my mistake. But as I said, this isn't a real problem as I'm just curious why bash behaves like that.

Comment: If you want to pass variables, create a script with the command in it and then set up an alias to that script. You can then pass the variables to the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases in `bash` do not take parameters of any form. Save the pain and use a function instead.

```
function lnn() {
    sed -n "${1}p" < "${2}"
}
```

Add the function to the file `00-alias.sh` and source it once before calling the function from command-line.

```
source /etc/profile.d/00-alias.sh
lnn 4 test.txt
```

See more information at [BashFAQ/80: How can I make an alias that takes an argument?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080)

> You can't. Aliases in bash are extremely rudimentary, and not really suitable to any serious purpose. The bash man page even says so explicitly:

An excerpt from the [`GNU bash man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), about aliases

> .. There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used.

---

On a side note the problem has nothing to do with relative paths (or) so, just remember aliases are *not* allowed in scripts. They're only allowed in interactive shells. If you're writing a script, always use a function instead.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly fine. I didn't know that arguments aren't allowed. You should probably mention that the line `alias lnn='lnn'` is still needed. (At least for me it only works with that line)

Comment: @NullDev: Once you add the function to the file and source it, the function is made available in the current shell, so you don't need the alias definition. ;)

Comment: Yea I did that but still received "ambiguous redirect". Maybe the file just didn't reload correctly

Comment: @NullDev: Which means you are missing any of the steps mentioned. The function should be available in the shell for command-line invocation once you source it

Comment: A safer form would be to use `awk` instead of `sed`, since you can properly pass variables: `awk -v ln="$1" 'NR == ln {print; exit; }' "$2"`.